# OpenAI embeddings API ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1536,) (3,)

Tags: openai-api

I'm trying to use the Embeddings API on a knowledge base and I already got the vectorized tokens out but now facing the below error:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1536,) (3,)

This is really odd since I followed the tutorial exactly and I guess the above error means there is a mismatch in terms of the dimensions of the two shapes. Why do they need to be same dimensions? Also, the CSV only has 1133 rows so not sure how its getting that 1536 figure?

The CSV I received from API (example row df.head()):

```
,text,n_tokens,embeddings
0,"""It's never too early to start off, right? Here is a quick guide for the young ones who want to position themselves well ..g universities will suffice (somewhat regarded as semi targets): Bristol, Bath, Durham, Nottingham, Cass Business School, York, KCL, Edinburgh, St Andrews and Manchester.[B]Extra Curricular Activities[/B]Having stellar academics will no longer suffice in getting a job or getting you into a good university. You should use this time to be building your soft skills as well as academic prowess. Banks place a very large focus on demonstrated leadership ability as well as team work and communication.",437,"[None, None, [0.006995666306465864, -0.0006904921028763056, 0.024300040677189827, -0.02906501479446888, -0.01895429566502571, 0.033895984292030334, -0.0230329018086195, -0.0039499117992818356, -0.0008072240161709487, -0.02164696715772152, 0.014690899290144444, -0.00037350095226429403, -0.010044720955193043, 0.019931050017476082, -0.0022917408496141434, -0.005085057578980923, 0.04281875863671303, -0.010757487267255783, 0.0075896382331848145, -0.0.....]]"
```

```
df = pd.read_csv('./embeddings.csv', index_col=0)
df['embeddings'] = df['embeddings'].apply(eval).apply(np.array,dtype='object')

df.head()


def create_context(
    question, df, max_len=1800, size="ada"
):
    """
    Create a context for a question by finding the most similar context from the dataframe
    """

    # Get the embeddings for the question
    q_embeddings = openai.Embedding.create(
        input=question, engine='text-embedding-ada-002')['data'][0]['embedding']

    # Get the distances from the embeddings
    df['distances'] = distances_from_embeddings(
        q_embeddings, df['embeddings'].values, distance_metric='cosine')

    returns = []
    cur_len = 0

    # Sort by distance and add the text to the context until the context is too long
    for i, row in df.sort_values('distances', ascending=True).iterrows():

        # Add the length of the text to the current length
        cur_len += row['n_tokens'] + 4

        # If the context is too long, break
        if cur_len > max_len:
            break

        # Else add it to the text that is being returned
        returns.append(row["text"])

    # Return the context
    return "\n\n###\n\n".join(returns)


def answer_question(
    df,
    model="text-davinci-003",
    question="Am I allowed to publish model outputs to Twitter, without a human review?",
    max_len=1800,
    size="ada",
    debug=False,
    max_tokens=150,
    stop_sequence=None
):
    """
    Answer a question based on the most similar context from the dataframe texts
    """
    context = create_context(
        question,
        df,
        max_len=max_len,
        size=size,
    )
    # If debug, print the raw model response
    if debug:
        print("Context:\n" + context)
        print("\n\n")

    try:
        # Create a completions using the question and context
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            prompt=f"Answer the question based on the context below, and if the question can't be answered based on the context, say \"I don't know\"\n\nContext: {context}\n\n---\n\nQuestion: {question}\nAnswer:",
            temperature=0,
            max_tokens=max_tokens,
            top_p=1,
            frequency_penalty=0,
            presence_penalty=0,
            stop=stop_sequence,
            model=model,
        )
        return response["choices"][0]["text"].strip()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return ""


answer_question(df, question="What day is it?", debug=False)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?